# How to properly import two top-level modules? - module has no attribute error

Tags: python, django

In the views.py file, I am importing a form to render a form. It also has a global variable defaultSelection and the get method would return the global variable.

```
#views.py
from .forms import testingForm

context = ('form', testingForm)

defaultSelection = 'A'

def getDefaultSelection():
     global defaultSelection
     return defaultSelection
```

In the form.py file, I was trying to retrieve the global variable

```
#form.py
from . import views

defaultSelection= views.getDefaultSelection()

class testingForm(forms.Form):
```

But I am getting a module has no attribute error importing the form in the views.py file

Comment: So you're trying to import a form from your forms.py and then import your view into your forms.py? And why are you using a global?

Comment: @CoryMadden Thanks for the reply Cory. I have a drop down select menu in one of the screens. And I would like to use the global variable to keep track of the selected value after I toggle between screens.

Comment: Two modules can't import each other.  Reorganize your code so that only one module needs to import the other.  Or put stuff in a third module, which both can then import.

Comment: As John Gordon said, you can't import your modules like that. Also, if you want to store something between screens you should use the session, not a global. I'm pretty sure you can't retain a global between views.

Comment: @CoryMadden I am very new to Django and Python. In terms of session, do you know if there's any example I could refer to?

Comment: I suggest you read either the official Django tutorial or the Mozilla Django tutorial, they both explain this clearly

Comment: You can't set a variable in memory and have it available to the user in the next request. Essentially, every variable is set per request/response cycle. Any data you want to persist (keep alive, save, maintain, etc) between requests must be explicitly saved somewhere, i.e. a database, the session (a session simply being a way of assosciating a set of data with some id supplied by the user for each request).